# Passing full directory path plus filename into String variable using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Borrowed the code and tweaked. Everything worked fine until strPath2 only receives filename instead of the entire file path. After searching there is surprisingly no answer.

I basically want to let Dir find any file that contain the word "Hello" in its filename. The start and the end of the filename varies. Is there any function/method that returns the full directory path with filename as String?

```
Sub TransferData()


    Dim strPath2 As String
    Dim wbkWorkbook1 As Workbook
    Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook

    strPath2 = Dir("C:\*Hello*.xlsx")

    Set wbkWorkbook1 = ThisWorkbook 
    Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath2)

    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J20").Copy
    wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple. I figured it out myself.

```
strPath2 = "C:\" & Dir("C:\*Hello*.xlsx")
```